# Jackson json two way object reference

Tags: java, jackson

I have a pair of objects like

```
public class Obj1 {
    public int id;
    public String name;
    public Obj2 obj2;
}

public class Obj2 {
    public int id;
    public String name;
    public List<Obj1> obj1list;
}
```

I want to be able to convert this to Json via Jackson. I found the `JsonManagedReference` and `JsonBackReference` and annotated them but when you do that, the serialization only works in one way. It will only show when the class with the `JsonManagedReference` side is serialized.

If I serialize an "Obj1" I want to see the "Obj2" that is attached to it. And if I serialize the "Obj2" I want to see the list of "Obj1"s that is attached to it.

I also tried using JsonIdentityInfo annotation like so

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
```

and this seems to work except that it adds the "id" value of the parent object into the subobject (or every subobject in the list case) which is a bit odd. Though I guess I can live with it.

Is there a way to get this to behave as I expect?

Comment: you named both classes `Obj1` you probably meant to name the 2nd as `Obj2`

Comment: Yea, sorry... I just wrote a simplified example

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are looking at `@JsonIgnoreProperties`, it will give what is needed and avoid json recursion.

```
public class Obj1 {
    public int id;
    public String name;
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("obj1list")
    public Obj2 obj2;
}

public class Obj2 {
    public int id;
    public String name;
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("obj2")
    public List<Obj1> obj1list;
}
```

**UPDATE** 

I always perfers `@JsonIgnoreProperties` over `JsonBackReference` and `JsonManagedReference`. As it not only does the trick, but also not escapes any data serialization (which is the case required here).

I also have a sample project on [github](https://github.com/amithkumarg/restapi-springboot-jpa) deals with this situation. Look for entity class codes `School.java` & `District.java`. Its an mvn spring-boot executable code, if you wanna run a test.

> From Javadoc, starting with Jackson 2.0, `@JsonIgnoreProperties` annotation can be applied both to classes and to properties. If used for both, actual set will be union of all ignorals: that is, you can only add properties to ignore, not remove or override. So you can not remove properties to ignore using per-property annotation.

**HOW IT WORKS**

When you define `@JsonIgnoreProperties` at propety level, while serialization/deserization it will work on the refered property object. 

So here, when `Obj1` is being parsed, you asked parser to ignore `obj1list` property of `obj2`. And similary, while parsing `Obj2` it will ignore contained `obj2` references in the `Obj` collection. So your parsing will look like below:

```
Obj1 : {
    id : int,
    name : string,
    Obj2 : {
     id : int,
     name : string
     obj1list : //ignored avoids recursion
    }
}

Obj2 : {
    id : int,
    name : string,
    obj1list : [{
     id : int,
     name : string,
     obj2 : //ignored avoids recursion
    },
    {
     id : int,
     name : string
     obj2 : //ignored avoids recursion
    }
    ]
}
```

Comment: That seems to do it, but why?