# How to Setup Complex Type with Inner Class (containing same JSON Key) as POJO for Marshalling Purposes using Jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson, nested-object

Am using Java 1.8 and FasterXML.

Suppose, you have an array list which consists of JSON Array:

```
[
    {
        "id": "8",
        "musician": {
            "band": {
                "bandId": "104"
            },
            "genre": {
                "type": "country",
                "typeId": 123
            },
            "musician": {
                "id": "87"
            }
        }
     },
     {
        "id": "9",
        "musician": {
            "band": {
                "bandId": "104"
            },
            "genre": {
                "type": "country",
                "typeId": 123
            },
            "musician": {
                "id": "88"
            }
        }
     }
]
```

---

```
public class Musician {

    private int id;
    private Band band;
    private Genre genre;

    // How to marshal this?
    private Musician musician;  

}
```

---

```
public class Band {

    private bandId;
}
```

---

```
public class Genre {

    private String type;
    private String typeId;
}
```

---

How to setup the top level class if you need to marshal the same type (which is `Musician`) from within the class?

Is there an annotation to use?

Should, I just name the inner Musician class to something else?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Musician {

    private int id;
    private Band band;
    private Genre genre;

    @JsonIgnoreProperties(["band", "genre"])
    private Musician musician;  

}
```

(I also suggest renaming the "musician" property into something that clarifies the actual relationship between the outer and inner property.)

Source: [Jackson json two way object reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50976307/jackson-json-two-way-object-reference)